Docker compose image not pulling from latest image from Gitlab when tag not specified
I am not able to get latest build docker image from Gitlab and problem is I need to specify tag(imageId) name every time I want to get the image in my docker compose file.
I have seen in other repositories the latest image is pulled when given the gitlab path of main branch in docker compose file, however in my case I need to give image id at the end of gitlab path as below in docker compose file.
I am expecting to have something like below to work for me in my docker compose file.
image: gitlabrepo_url/branch_name (This should pull latest image)
however below is what I am always needing to do
image: gitlabrepo_url/branch_name:123456(image tag) need to explicitly specify the tag every time. 

In your pipeline, do you explicitly push something with the latest tag?  latest doesn't have any special meaning, it just happens to be the default tag; if there's not a ...:latest image then you can't run it, and latest won't change if other tags are pushed.

Please provide a [mcve].
